# setting RAW datatype through prepared statement

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc

I have a column in the table column name is INSTANCE_GUID its raw data type.

I am writing a prepared statement select query to  and setting INSTANCE_GUID

```
pstatement.setString(instanceGuid);
```

But is this the right way to set a raw data type.Please let me know  how to set the RAW dataType should i use setByte?

Thanks

Comment: http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/misc/datatypes/raw.html

Comment: Next time, make sure you include this kind of info.

Comment: `RAW` is deprecated, you should be using `BLOB` instead.

Answer (score 5):

As described in the [Oracle JDBC Developer's guide and reference 11g](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/java.111/b31224/datacc.htm#BHCJBJCC), when using a `RAW` column, you can treat it as a `BINARY` or `VARBINARY` JDBC type, which means you can use the JDBC standard methods `getBytes()` and `setBytes()` which returns or accepts a `byte[]`. `setBytes()` will accept a long array (> 4000 bytes).

The other options is to use the Oracle driver specific extensions `getRAW()` (`oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet`) and `setRAW()` (`oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement`) which return or accept a [`oracle.sql.RAW`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e13995/oracle/sql/RAW.html). Using these two will require you to unwrap and/or cast to the specific Oracle implementation class.

To create one, just call `new oracle.sql.RAW(byte[])`.

Comment: Which interface defines `setRAW()`?

Comment: @AaronDigulla it is defined by `oracle.jdbc.OraclePreparedStatement` (and `getRAW` by `oracle.jdbc.OracleResultSet`)

Comment: Thanks, please verify my edits. I could insert a 13MB `byte[]` array into a table using `PreparedStatement.setBytes()`. In this way, this outdated datatype is better than LOB.