# ResultSet coming as empty after executing query

Tags: sql, jdbc

I have a query

```
SELECT instance_guid FROM service_instances WHERE service_template_guid='E578F99360A86E4EE043C28DE50A1D84' AND service_family_name='TEST'
```

Directly executing this returns me

```
4FEFDE7671A760A8DC8FC63CFBFC8316
F2F9DF641D8E2CACC03175A7A628D51D
```

Now I am trying same code from JDBC.

```
 PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = executionContext.getConnection();
            if (conn != null) {
                ps = (PreparedStatement)conn.prepareStatement(query);
                if (params == null) params = new Object[0];
                for (int i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
                    if (params[i] instanceof Integer) {
                        ps.setInt(i+1, ((Integer)params[i]).intValue());
                    } else if (params[i] instanceof java.util.Date) {                        
                        ((PreparedStatement)ps).setDATE(i+1, new oracle.sql.DATE((new java.sql.Timestamp(((Date)params[i]).getTime()))));
                        //ps.setObject(i+1, new oracle.sql.DATE(new Time(((Date)params[i]).getTime())));
                    } else {
                        if (params[i] == null) params[i] = "";
                        ps.setString(i+1, params[i].toString());
                    }
                }

                rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

I see `params[0] =E578F99360A86E4EE043C28DE50A1D84 and params[1]=TEST`

But the resultSet is empty and not getting the result.I debugged but not much help?

Can you please let me know Am i trying right?

In java its defined as below

```
  final static private String INSTANCE_GUID_BY_TEMPLATE_GUID = 
    "SELECT instance_guid FROM service_instances WHERE service_template_guid=? AND service_family_name=? "

SERVICE_FAMILY_NAME          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(256)  
SERVICE_TEMPLATE_GUID        NOT NULL RAW(16 BYTE)
```

Comment: Presume that `query` string does have correct sql statement.

Comment: Query string has same statement.I am trying same statement in db with parameters replaced

Comment: show us the query string as it is defined inside of Java please.

Comment: @constantlearner `SERVICE_TEMPLATE_GUID` is of type `RAW` and do have `RAW` data type set method?

Comment: @Polppan if OP uses setRAW/getRAW he will be bound to the oracle JDBC driver.  My post below addresses that.

Comment: @Woot4Moo That might solve the problem. Was wondering whether having a for loop to check data type is a good idea or not? Is this a good practice?

Comment: @Polppan oh yeah that is not a good practice. OP stated it is because of a framework they are using.

Answer (score 3):

First and foremost this breaks every sql mapping pattern I have ever seen.

```
String sql = "SELECT instance_guid FROM service_instances WHERE service_template_guid=? AND service_family_name=?";
PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            conn = executionContext.getConnection();  
            ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);  
            ps.setString(1,guid);  
            ps.setString(2,family);  
            rs = ps.executeQuery();  
            while(rs.next(){...}  
           ...  
       }
```

You should not be dynamically figuring out the data types as they come in, unless you are trying to write some code to port from database X to database Y.

**UPDATE**

I see you are using RAW as a datatype, from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13745213/205426):

> As described in the Oracle JDBC Developer's guide and reference 11g,
>   when using a RAW column, you can treat it as a BINARY or VARBINARY
>   JDBC type, which means you can use the JDBC standard methods
>   getBytes() and setBytes() which returns or accepts a byte[]. The other
>   options is to use the Oracle driver specific extensions getRAW() and
>   setRAW() which return or accept a oracle.sql.RAW. Using these two will
>   require you to unwrap and/or cast to the specific Oracle
>   implementation class.

Further from a code readability standpoint, your solution makes it painful for a new developer to take over.  Far too often I see people making sql be "dynamic" when in reality 99% of the time you don't need this level of dynamic query building.  It sounds good in most people's heads but it just causes pain and suffering in the SDLC.

Comment: I am sending this to some framework code which I cannot change they have designed in generic way

Comment: In debugger i can see I can see its going to else block and setting the String

Comment: @constantlearner try to run it from just a main as I have laid out and see if it works, if so it may mean the framework is busted.

Comment: I am sending other query for  same generic framework.It works fine.Final static private String TEMPLATE_NAME = 
    "SELECT SERVICE_NAME FROM service_templates  WHERE service_template_guid=?  " The service_template_guid is of type raw